# play 2.5 framework adding a session variable/ reading a session variable in a filter

Tags: java, playframework

I am struggling to add a session variable in a play filter.

I know I can get `requestHeader.cookies().get("search_id").value()` but if it's `null`, how do I set it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(myCookie == null) session("search_id", newSearchIdValue);
```

Also, see [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaSessionFlash#storing-data-into-the-session).